# How to populate a listview inside a fragment with data from another fragment?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to populate my Listview using the data from another fragment.

I am able to get the data from the other fragment, but when I try to make my listview object, it is returning null.

As a result, the app is crashing.

I am getting data from the user from one fragment and then calling a method from another fragment to pass the data. I am making my listview object and array adapter in the poplist() method of the second method. However, the app is crashing due to null pointer exception. 
Please help.

```
public class WishListFragment extends Fragment {
   ArrayList<String> wishListTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
   View rootView;
   ListView wishListView;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Context context = getActivity();
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wish_list, container, false);
      return rootView;
   }

   // Another fragment gets the data from user as strings and calls this method
public void popList(String str1, String str2, String str3, Context context) 
{
 // LibModel is a pojo, I am using its constructor to set the values.

 LibModel lm = new LibModel(str1,str2,str3);

    Log.w("Title:",lm.getTitle());
    Log.w("Author:",lm.getAuthor());
    Log.w("Language:",lm.getLang());

        wishListTitles.add(lm.getTitle());

        // I get this on the log, so the ArrayList is made correctly
        Log.w("ArrayList:",wishListTitles.get(0));

        // The listView gives Null Pointer exception and crashes the app
        wishListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wl_lv);
        ArrayAdapter<String> wishListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wishListTitles);

        wishListView.setAdapter(wishListAdapter);
    }
}
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work

1. Used getView method instead of rootView while making the Listview.
2. Tried to make the listview inside the onCreateView() method but then the listview object is null, I get null pointer.

I am unable to find a way to put the set the adapter for the listview as it is returning Null.

Comment: pass data from FragmentOne to Fragmenttwo via bunlde, get it at Fragmenttwo and populate to adapter/Listview/recyclerview.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having interface callback in the fragment with the data. Also keep a reference of the list view in the activity containing the fragment. 
Upon callback, the interface function will be executed and you can update list view from there.